# How do I add more Ethernet ports to expand on those my router already has?

Tags: switch, router, ethernet

This may have been asked before, so apologies, but without knowledge of correct terminology I was unable to find a related question.

The router provided by my ISP has four gigabit ethernet ports.  They are all used up, but I could do with some more (I prefer wired networks to wireless).

Is this possible , I know  I need more hardware but don't know what to look for.

The current set up is:

```
[ISP Modem] ---> [Asus RT-N66U Router] 
                        |
                        └┄> Devices 1-4 (wired)
```

My research suggests I need something called a "switch".  Is that correct?  If so, how would it connect up to the existing equipment please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a switch with a number of ports equal to, or more than, the number of hosts you need to connect. Simply, connect one port from the router to the switch, then connect other ports on your switch to the hosts (spread networks).

Comment: You also need a port to use for uplink purposes, so to hook up an additional N hosts, you need (at a minimum, assuming a single one) a switch with N+1 ports total. So a switch "with a number of ports equal to the number of hosts you need to connect" will possibly be insufficient.